# Create a long list where each element of one list is repeated/ multiplied by a value from another dataframe

Tags: r, list, vector, matrix-multiplication, vector-multiplication

I have run into a bit of a conundrum that I can't find any obvious answers to on stack overflow, so wondered if I could please pick the expertise hive mind!

I basically have a list of providers, which I have grouped by region to get the number of providers per region, and I also then have that total divided by a number of terms I want to assign them to and rounded (12 terms).

It looks like this:

| region | total | term |
| --- | --- | --- |
| East Midlands | 24 | 2 |
| NEYH | 46 | 4 |

and so on.

I have a list of the 12 terms (Spring 2021, Summer 2021, and so on up to Summer 2026), and I want to multiply (or repeat) each element of this list, by the term value for each region. So for instance East Midlands would be 2 x each term, so would look like:

| region | assigned term |
| --- | --- |
| East Midlands | Spring 2021 |
| East Midlands | Spring 2021 |
| East Midlands | Summer 2021 |
| East Midlands | Summer 2021 |

and so on. For NEYH Spring 2021 would repeat 4 times, before moving onto Summer 2021 4 times, etc, all the way up to Summer 2026. I ideally want this in a long list, so I can then join it back onto my main dataset by region and it will be in the correct order for each region, although there is probably a better way of doing this!

I have not created any code that remotely works for this problem, I was trying for loops but got nowhere fast. Grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(region = c("East Midlands", "NEYH"), 
                 total = c(24, 46), 
                 term = c(2, 4))
> df

             region total term
    1 East Midlands    24    2
    2          NEYH    46    4
```

**Code**

```
terms <- do.call("c", 
                 sapply(1:length(df$term), 
                        function(x) rep(paste(c("Spring", "Summer"), c(2021:2026, 2021:2026)), 
                                        each = df$term[x]))) 
region <- do.call("c", 
                   sapply(1:length(df$term), 
                          function(x) rep(rep(df$region[x], 
                                          times = df$term[x]), times = 12)))
final_df <- cbind.data.frame(region, terms)
```

**Output**

```
> final_df
          region       terms
1  East Midlands Spring 2021
2  East Midlands Spring 2021
3  East Midlands Summer 2022
4  East Midlands Summer 2022
5  East Midlands Spring 2023
6  East Midlands Spring 2023
7  East Midlands Summer 2024
8  East Midlands Summer 2024
9  East Midlands Spring 2025
10 East Midlands Spring 2025
11 East Midlands Summer 2026
12 East Midlands Summer 2026
13 East Midlands Spring 2021
14 East Midlands Spring 2021
15 East Midlands Summer 2022
16 East Midlands Summer 2022
17 East Midlands Spring 2023
18 East Midlands Spring 2023
19 East Midlands Summer 2024
20 East Midlands Summer 2024
21 East Midlands Spring 2025
22 East Midlands Spring 2025
23 East Midlands Summer 2026
24 East Midlands Summer 2026
25          NEYH Spring 2021
26          NEYH Spring 2021
27          NEYH Spring 2021
28          NEYH Spring 2021
29          NEYH Summer 2022
30          NEYH Summer 2022
31          NEYH Summer 2022
32          NEYH Summer 2022
33          NEYH Spring 2023
34          NEYH Spring 2023
35          NEYH Spring 2023
36          NEYH Spring 2023
37          NEYH Summer 2024
38          NEYH Summer 2024
39          NEYH Summer 2024
40          NEYH Summer 2024
41          NEYH Spring 2025
42          NEYH Spring 2025
43          NEYH Spring 2025
44          NEYH Spring 2025
45          NEYH Summer 2026
46          NEYH Summer 2026
47          NEYH Summer 2026
48          NEYH Summer 2026
49          NEYH Spring 2021
50          NEYH Spring 2021
51          NEYH Spring 2021
52          NEYH Spring 2021
53          NEYH Summer 2022
54          NEYH Summer 2022
55          NEYH Summer 2022
56          NEYH Summer 2022
57          NEYH Spring 2023
58          NEYH Spring 2023
59          NEYH Spring 2023
60          NEYH Spring 2023
61          NEYH Summer 2024
62          NEYH Summer 2024
63          NEYH Summer 2024
64          NEYH Summer 2024
65          NEYH Spring 2025
66          NEYH Spring 2025
67          NEYH Spring 2025
68          NEYH Spring 2025
69          NEYH Summer 2026
70          NEYH Summer 2026
71          NEYH Summer 2026
72          NEYH Summer 2026
```

**Explanation**

We replicate the terms and regions according to the given information with `sapply()` and `rep()` and then concatenate the resulting list of vectors with `do.call()` and `c()`.